# Sign in & Slide Out format

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have a question and would love to get some feedback from you all. I'm stuck in a situation with my code that will not slide left to right. I have a SignUp/SignIn form and I need the slide in animation going left to right when you click either those 2 buttons. I feel like I have everything intact but it just does not want to work! :( Any help will be a blessing.

```js
window.onload - function() {
  const signupButton = document.getElementById('signup');
  const signinButton = document.getElementById('signin');
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
  });

  signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
  });

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Monteserrat", sans-serif;
  background: #f6f5f7;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: -20px 0 50px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  margin: 20px 0 30px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.container {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 768px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 480px;
}

.form-container form {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 50px;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-container {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.social-container a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

.form-container input {
  background: #eee;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  #ff4b2b;
  background: #ff4b2b;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px 45px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: transform 80ms ease-in;
}

button:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button.ghost {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.form {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 50px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 00;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.6 ease-in-out;
}

.sign-in-container {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sign-up-container {
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay {
  background: #ff416c;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff4b2b, #ff416c) no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.overlay-right {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.overlay-left {
  transform: translateX(-20%);
}


/* Animation */


/* Move sign in to the right */

.container.right-panel-active .sign-In-container {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay-container {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.container.right-panel-active .sign-up-container {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 5;
}

.container.right-panel-active .overlay {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="buttonwork.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <div class="form-container sign-up-container">
    <form action="#">
      <h1>Create Account</h1>
      <div class="social-container">
        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      </div>
      <span>or use your email for registration</span>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button>Sign Up</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-container sign-in-container">
    <form action="#">
      <h1>Sign in</h1>
      <div class="social-container">
        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="social"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
      </div>
      <span>or use your account</span>
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
      <button>Sign In</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-left">
        <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
        <p>To keep connected with us please login with your personal info</p>
        <button class="ghost" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-panel overlay-right">
        <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
        <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
        <button class="ghost" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>

</footer>


</html>
```

Thanks again!

Dominik

Answer (score 0):

You just have a few typo in your javascript code . Your "signup" and "signin" should be "signUp" and "signIn"

```
const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
const container = document.getElementById('container');

signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
});

signInButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
});
```

Here is the codepen if you want to see it in action => https://codepen.io/l0609890/pen/dyyKBeo

Comment: Thank you Henry for your comment. I use brackets to type my code in & it still will not slide over when I try to refresh my page. The "Live Preview" always seems to end like 5 seconds after reloading the page. I do not know if that has something to do with it or not. Would you prefer another code editor?

Comment: Hmm, this shouldn't be a coding editor problem. The code that you have given me seems to work fine except the javascript part. How about I paste the entire javascript code and you tell me how it works for you

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: I was actually just thinking about your situation, in the beginning are you clicking the "signup" button or the "signin" button

Comment: I'm glad that you brought that up! I was clicking "Sign in" at first, so I went back to double-check myself and it still isn't transitioning over. :(

Comment: You should only be clicking the buttons in the color boxes if you want it to slide

Comment: I have tried & still nothing has changed. It says "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null". & it has an error at "signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
 container.classList.add("right-panel-active"); "

Answer (score 0):

In React we don't directly mutate the DOM. It is also considered anti-pattern to query the DOM to access the DOMNodes (document.getElementById), use React refs instead to gain access to the underlying DOMNodes. I have converted it in react hope it helps

In this case you should use and update some React state to conditionally add the "right-panel-active" class to the ".container" div element.

```
const SignInForm = () => {
  const [swapPanel, setSwapPanel] = useState(false);

  const signUpButton = () => {
    setSwapPanel(true);
  };
  const signInButton = () => {
    setSwapPanel(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="sigin">
      <div
        className={["container", swapPanel ? "right-panel-active" : null]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" ")}
        id="container"
      >
        <div className="form-container sign-up-container">
          <form action="#">
            <h1>Create Account</h1>
            <div className="social-container"></div>
            <span>or use your email for registration</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <button onClick={signUpButton}>Sign Up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="form-container sign-in-container">
          <form action="#">
            <h1>Sign in</h1>
            <div className="social-container"></div>
            <span>or use your account</span>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            Forgot your password?
            {/* <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a> */}
            <button onClick={signInButton}>Sign In</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div className="overlay-container">
          <div className="overlay">
            <div className="overlay-panel overlay-left">
              <h1>Welcome Back!</h1>
              <p>
                To keep connected with us please login with your personal info
              </p>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={signInButton}
                className="ghost"
                id="signIn"
              >
                Sign In
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="overlay-panel overlay-right">
              <h1>Hello, Friend!</h1>
              <p>Enter your personal details and start journey with us</p>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={signUpButton}
                className="ghost"
                id="signUp"
              >
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```